# Matplotlib Draw a Constant y Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use matpoltlib to make a plot that with a constant y axis(always from 0 to 14 and the gap is 1), since I want to make labels for them and my dot values will be(x, y) where y is from 0 to 14 gap 1, and a changing x axis. I already tried to play with y ticks. And here is my code for that:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 14, 1))
    labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_yticklabels()]
    labels[1] = 'Not Detected'
    labels[2] = 'A/G'
    labels[3] = 'G/G'
    labels[4] = 'C/T'
    labels[5] = 'C/C'
    labels[6] = 'A/A'
    labels[7] = '-1'
    labels[8] = 'ε3/ε3'
    labels[9] = 'A/C'
    labels[10] = 'T/T'
    labels[11] = 'C/G'
    labels[12] = 'ε2/ε3'
    labels[13] = 'G/T'

    ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

what I'm thinking about is to use some values or lines with white color so those y axis will appear. But I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing it. And here is the diagram I generated with the current code. It only shows C/C right now and I want all labels to appear in the diagram.
[image]

I tried draw white points with:

```
    x1 = np.arange(n)
    y1 = np.arange(1,15,1)
    plt.scatter(x1,y1,color = 'white')
```

Which did give me what I want: But I was wondering whether there is a lib setting that can do this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just using a [fixed locator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) and [fixed formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) for your y axis. The function, ax.set_yticklabels() is simply a convenience wrapper for these tick methods.

I would also recommend having your y_labels in a list or using a loop structure as this is a more generalizable and modifiable implementation.

If I'm understanding the goals of your plot correctly, something like this may work well for you.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

#make some data
x = np.arange(25)
y = np.random.randint(1, 14, size=25)

#convert y labels to a list
y_labels = [
    'Not Detected','A/G','G/G','C/T','C/C','A/A',
    '-1','ε3/ε3', 'A/C','T/T','C/G','ε2/ε3','G/T'
    ]

#define figure/ax and set figsize
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
#plot data, s is marker size, it's points squared 
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='x', s=10**2, color='#5d2287', linewidth=2)

#set major locator and formatter to fixed, add grid, hide top/right spines
locator   = ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.ticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(1, 14)))
formatter = ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FixedFormatter(y_labels))
grid      = ax.grid(axis='y', dashes=(8,3), alpha=0.3, color='gray')
spines    = [ax.spines[x].set_visible(False) for x in ['top','right']]
params    = ax.tick_params(labelsize=12) #increase label font size
```